# When I try to access a javascript object's key, it's telling me it's undefined even though it exists?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request, es6-promise

So the following is my function which is being invoked:

```
function* makeRequest(payload) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      request(payload,
        function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('body', body);
            console.log('body.success', body.success);
            resolve(body);
        });
   });
}
```

the output of `console.log('body', body);` is the following:

`{
  "success": true,
  "challenge_ts": "2018-09-29T21:09:13Z",
  "hostname": "localhost"
}`

so `body` clearly does contain an object which ought to be accessible. However, when trying to access `body.success` all I'm getting is `undefined`... any ideas on why this may be the case?

Comment: Did you forget to parse a json string payload? Logging an object would be "object object" or similar.

Comment: Why is that a generator function?

Comment: Please `console.log(typeof body)` (to confirm @spender's suspicion)

Comment: ok, ill log the typeof body

Comment: @Bergi yes, it's a string not an object...which is weird. I guess I'll just JSON.parse(body) then?

Comment: @Bergi it's a generator function because I'm yielding it to reduce the amount of code, I hate dealing with chained promises

Comment: @Mason0958 If you don't like chaining promises with `.then()`, you should use `async`/`await`. Not generators.

Comment: @Mason0958 Yes, just parse it. Why did you expect `request` to do that for you?

Comment: @Bergi generators are cleaner, not a big fan of async/await

Comment: @Bergi never had this problem before, I expected it to be parsed

Comment: @Mason0958 generators are not cleaner, you always need to wrap them in a runner function that awaits the promises for you. Or did you handcraft something that doesn't work exactly like async/await?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out, the body of the response in the request library can be a string. I was able to confirm it's a string using the method as recommended by @Bergi to console.log(typeof body).

So the solution is to set `body = JSON.parse(body);` in order to parse the stringified object back into an actual object.